# Is this a good asp.net website architecture choice?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am currently working on an asp.net website and I am using web forms. I have some experience building asp.net websites before using the server controls(grid view,charts,etc) and I feel they are slow. I tried some jquery suites that have all the controls(grid,chart,tree,etc), at least the ones I need, and I like them mostly because of their speed and improved user experience. I am planning to not use any asp server controls and use plain html and the jquery plugins instead on my website.

Is it a good choice to not use any asp.net server controls and move most of the processing to client side?

I know that if the client browser has javascript turned off, then my site won't work at all.

But other than that, what problems I might face in view of our future plans to develop mobile application and/or implement MVC ?

Why should I use asp.net server controls at all if every thing is finally rendered as html and when I can get/post data using jquery ajax requests?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using the ASP.NET controls then you are not really using ASP.NET webforms. The controls are what give you the client and server side interaction.

With what you are stating it sounds like MVC is the way to go from the start. The default projects have jQuery already included and since there are no MVC controls it is simply HTML and Javascript passing you GET/POST to the controllers.

Also the JSON support allows really nice, clean and light interaction of data with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Far from being a complete answer I wanted to provide my 2 cents.  If you are working with .NET for any website, my humble opinion is that you should use MVC.  With MVC you have better separation of the business layer and the UI.

You can easily create support for your APIs by creating controllers that support xml or json responses, so that will help with your rich user interface, using frameworks like jquery, extjs, etc. and will ready you to support mobile as well with the same API.

Answer (score 0):

I was in your situation about a year ago and came to the same conclusion you did.

Going further, I realized that I didn't even need aspx page: just build HTML5 pages with a masterpage that injects json data on page load using literals (the only asp.net control I use) and then, work with WCF to implement a service-oriented architecture to transfer data back and forth using jquery ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like Microsoft MVC - but that's just me.

MVC is a pattern, not a technology, so you can implement it however you want.

Something you might consider doing if you don't want to learn Microsoft's MVC implementation, still use WebForms, but do it using an MVC style is develop your application like this:

VIEW: ASP.NET page (no server side controls) `builds` page

CONTROLLER: jQuery / Javascript `calls` Generic Handler file (ASHX) and `returns` JSON

MODEL: ASHX `calls` model (your custom classes)

This way, you're using an MVC pattern, but you're not tied down to Microsoft's implementation of it and now, you can develop both a website and a mobile application using the same controllers because your controller level is exposed via an ASHX file.

Hope that makes sense.

You'd obviously have to handle security and access to your ASHX files, etc.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Looks like I am using the exact same pattern,which you described in your reply, on my website. So far it is working great. do you know of any security issues that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

First I think "server controls" and server-side deserves to be differentiated.

- sure you can do all the front end in HTML/JS
- if you have data sources outside of the browser you will need to at least communicate with the "server side" whatever it maybe. This has nothing to do with "server controls"
- validation/security - you can't do all of that on the client side. *Everything* on the client side can be viewed/tampered
- as already answered, MVC doesn't *need* controls - just clarifying that you *can* use controls in ASP.Net MVC. The core concept is **its all ASP.Net** under the covers and you can mix/match as you please - even languages (VB.Net, C#)

Web forms still has its place and nothing about it hinders jQuery or whatever.

"Slow" is dependent on a lot of things. I wouldn't blame Web Forms (the technology) **at all**. Mistakes in code happens, no matter what technology.